# Moving a tableview cell from one section to another but receiving an error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a **tableview** where I am trying to move one cell from one section to another. However, when I try to do this, I get a `'Fatal Error: Index out of range'` on the line, `goals[1].append(goals[0][indexPath.row])`.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class GoalsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var goalTableView: UITableView!

let sections: [String] = ["Mark as Complete:", "History:"]
var goals: [[String]] = [] //This is like this because the cell is also transported from another table view in a separate view controller to this table view. 
let theEmptyModel: [String] = ["No data in this section."]
extension GoalsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if goals.indices.contains(section) {
            return goals[section].count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodayGoalViewCell_1", for: indexPath) as? GoalTableViewCell
            cell?.goalLabel.text = goals[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            cell?.cellDelegate = self
            cell?.index = indexPath
            return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            progressBarAnimation()

            if goals[0] != theEmptyModel {
                goals[1].append(goals[0][indexPath.row])
                if goals[1].first!.contains("No data in this section.") {
                    goals[1].removeFirst()
                }
                goals[0].remove(at: indexPath.row)
                if goals[0].count == 0 {
                    goals[0].append(contentsOf: theEmptyModel)
                }
                tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of these subscript calls fails `goals[1]` or `goals[0]` or `[indexPath.row]` - try to debug or print the array. To avoid a hard crash use `get()` from this extension:

```
extension Array {
    func get(_ index: Int) -> Element? {
        if 0 <= index && index < count {
            return self[index]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Use `guard` checks at the beginning of your method or `if` statement.